# Unflatten Mysql rows which contain parent/child into PHP objects

Tags: php, mysql, oop

Is their something out there which can 'unflatten' results from a SQL/MySQL query into an array of PHP objects, building up the parent child relationship structure?

Often I find executing queries against my database for a quick parent/child result needs to be done with two queries.  One to grab the parents, the other to grab the children.  For complex queries this can sometimes be a bit slow (even with the proper indexing etc. in place).

It's far quicker to just hit up the DB with one query - and get my parent/child data in one response.  I wonder if there is a generic way to join the stuff together, because I'd like to do this more often...

A simple example:

```
SELECT CountryID, Country, CityID, City FROM country INNER JOIN city ON city.CountryID = country.CountryID ORDER BY CountryID
```

The results from the query:

1,USA,50,New York

1,USA,51,Las Vegas

2,Australia,52,Sydney

And the object structure afterwards would be (i've just chucked it in XML format for readability to understand the object structure im hoping to acheive):

```
<Results>
  <Country ID="1" Name="USA">
   <Children>
    <City ID="50" Name="New York"/>
    <City ID="51" Name="Las Vegas"/>
   </Children>
  <Country ID="2" Name="Australia"/>
   <Children>
    <City ID="52" Name="Sydney"/>
   </Children>
  </Country>
</Results>
```

I'd be awesome if this was possible, perhaps even with endless depth.  i.e. Parent, Child, ChildChild relationships...

Cheers, Luc!

Comment: Have a nice lecture :) http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database/

Comment: Wow that's interesting. I wonder if somebody has written similar code to this to wrap around a typical parent child database structure rather than changing the way things are stored. I think this has given me inspiration to come up with something.

Comment: :) the way to store isn't an option here (at least for an unknown tree depth). You must have a linear table with an idParent column which points every node to its parent. The point here is how you choose to generate your tree depending on your needs..glad i could help :)

Comment: Thanks catalin. I'll have something to post tomorrow! What's a good site to share cool php code?

Comment: The code you make yourself and for ideeas, SO is pretty much ok :) you don't need to get the code, you need to learn basic programming techniques and everything will come much easier to you...

Comment: threee years later, I know but... what do you want? an object of class country with cities as properties? several objects of class city extending countries? an xml structure does not really translate in objects...